# URL Rewrite in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a Wordpress url and here is same regex101

https://regex101.com/r/DHUIKX/1

Code in wordpress functions.php

```
add_rewrite_rule('jobs\/\??\w+=([^&]+)&?\??\w+=([^&]+)&?','job_listing_region=$1/&job_listing_region=$2/','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

And the code in .htaccess file is

```
RewriteRule ^jobs\/\??\w+=([^&]+)&?\??\w+=([^&]+)&? /job_listing_region=$1/&job_listing_region=$matches[1]/ [QSA,L]
```

But nothing is working. It takes me to a 404 page. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong. And the URL in browser is also not changing even I saved perma links in wordpress.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the browser to another URL, or add pretty URLs in WP? Your second parameter to `add_rewrite_rule()` looks wrong, look at [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_rewrite_rule) for examples.

Comment: @janh2 I just want to make url pretty

Comment: No need for the .htaccess RewriteRule then. Have you looked at the examples from the docs I linked?

Comment: @janh2 Yes I looked at it, can you let me know what exactly is wrong. When I write rewrite function, the line was atomically appended in .htaccess file.

Comment: '/job_listing_region...' vs 'index.php?job_listing_region=...' etc. Did you also add them as rewrite tags?

Comment: @janh2 they are custom taxonomies. Can you ask you if we need index.php as index.php is not included in original URL

http://example.com/jobs/?job_listing_region=california&job_listing_category=alcohol-abuse-programs

Comment: @janh2 I changed to

index.php?job_listing_region=$1/&job_listing_region=$2/

But still not wokring